# Config restcomm ussd gateway

Tags: restcomm

I install restcomm ussd gateway on my server but can not config it
I tried but did not work
I just want to send a real ussd push message to my phone number
How to config it?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1YbQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this, you might want to follow up on the discussion in the Restcomm Google Groups [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/restcomm/FQZkbl0U8V4/8AsOfaBAAgAJ), as this same question was posted there too.